# Avoid deadlocking within a serializable isolation-level transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sqltransaction

I am trying to implement an event source in SQL Server, and have been experiencing deadlocking issues.

In my design, events are grouped by `DatasetId` and each event is written with a `SequenceId`, with the requirement that, for a given `DatasetId`, `SequenceId`s are serial, beginning at 1 and increasing one at a time with each event, never missing a value and never repeating one either.

My `Events` table looks something like:

```
CREATE TABLE [Events]
(
    [Id] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DatasetId] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [SequenceId] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

I also have a non-unique, non-clustered index on the `DatasetId` column.

In order to insert into this table with the above restrictions on `SequenceId`, I have been inserting rows under a transaction using Serializable isolation level, and calculating the required `SequenceId` manually within this transaction as the max of all existing `SequenceId`s plus one:

```
DECLARE @DatasetId BIGINT = 1, @Value NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'I am an event.';

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY

    DECLARE @SequenceId BIGINT;
    SELECT @SequenceId = ISNULL(MAX([SequenceId]), 0) + 1
    FROM [Events]
    WHERE [DatasetId] = @DatasetId;

    INSERT INTO [Events] ([DatasetId], [SequenceId], [Value])
    VALUES (@DatasetId, @SequenceId, @Value);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

END CATCH
```

This has worked fine in terms of the guarantees that I require on the `SequenceId` column. However, I have been experiencing deadlocking when trying to insert multiple rows in parallel, even when such rows are for different `DatasetId`s.

The behaviour seems to be that the query to generate a `SequenceId` in a first connection blocks the same query to generate a `SequenceId` in the second connection, and this second attempt blocks the first connections ability to insert the row, meaning neither transaction is able to complete, hence the deadlock.

Is there a means of avoiding this whilst still gaining the benefits of a Serializable transaction isolation level?

Another technique I have been considering is reducing the isolation level and instead using `sp_getapplock` to manually acquire a lock on the table for a given `DatasetId`, meaning I can then ensure I can generate a consistent `SequenceId`. Once the transaction has been committed/rolled back, the lock would automatically be released. Is this approach reasonable, or is manually managing locks like this considered an anti-pattern?

Comment: You might want to read [The Serializable Isolation Level](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-serializable-isolation-level) - because it doesn't stop concurrent queries operating concurrently, it only specified what the results must be. Therefore it doesn't promise to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Given you are using `MAX([SequenceId])` you really want to be the exclusive user of the table while you are getting the value and while you are setting the value. Therefore taking an exclusive table lock for the transaction is an option, as is using `sp_getapplock`

Comment: Although last time I tried using `sp_getapplock` in such a situation, it gave me deadlocks. So I went back to an exclusive table lock.

Comment: Seems you missed the  DatasetId=@ DatasetId condition in SELECT @ SequenceId = ISNULL(MAX([SequenceId]), 0) + 1
    FROM [Events];
Also I think read committed is good enough for your scenario. YOu just need to add the hint HOLDLOCK in the SELECT for the @ SequenceId

Comment: Also you need to change the isolation level before starting the trx.

Comment: Thanks @PeterHe, I've fixed in the example code. The example above was not the actual code however, and these issues do not exist in the actual code so are not responsible for the deadlocking.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I had a mistake in my original question which has now been fixed - because the query to calculate the `SequenceId` filters by `DatasetId`, the lock taken should in theory (from my understanding) only be taken on the single `DatasetId` owing to the presence of the non-clustered index on this column.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I should also make clear that I understand that Serializable transactions do not guarantee to avoid deadlocking, but I dont understand where the deadlock is coming from, given the structure of the query and the expected behaviour of the serializable transaction locking. I am performing a read (using the aggregate `MAX` function) and then a write on a single table, and so I'm not sure how two queries can deadlock here. If the first query obtains a lock it should stop the second query from doing so, and so the first query should be able to complete without issue.

Comment: @DaleBurrell I am assuming there is something going on here with lock level escalation, but my SQL-fu is not strong enough to understand the details involved.

Comment: @PeterHe I will try the suggestion using READ COMMITTED and HOLDLOCK hint and see if that works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Pull the deadlock graph and inspect exactly what order and what level the locks being taken are (you'll need to google accessing the deadlock graph). And if you need help deciphering it, I suggest posting over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ as they are the experts.

Comment: @AlexDawes did you find the reason for this behavior?